# Android Security Changing UID

Tags: android, security

1) Is it possible to **CHANGE UID**  if i get a **ROOT ACCESS** to my android device ?

2) If 2 Appz developed by same developer having **SHARE ID** with different **Applications permissions** will work ?

Comment: what are you talking about, all apps run with different uids.  To change this you have to modify the firmware.  Point number two doesn't make any sense, rephrase it.

Comment: @KristopherMicinski That is not accurace. Two applications can run with the same UID on an Android device if they both are signed with the same developer certificate and they both specify the same desired UID in their manifest. No root access is necessary for this.

Comment: I never said that it was necessary to have root access did I?  The OP's question reffered to *his* UID -- which doesn't make any sense -- since all apps (sans the case you mention) run with different uids.  He never mentioned that he was changing the app UID anywhere, did he?  Sorry, I didn't see that if so.  Along with this, running with the same uid for different apps has been explicitly cited as a bad idea, see this thread: http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/07b0693b3f0370d8/a51a14563f1a66b6?lnk=raot

Comment: Agree, a user's UID doesn't make any sense. And there are legitimate use cases for two apps running under the same UID (apps that are part of a suite, for example)...they are rare but they do exist. Cheers!

Comment: Sorry if my question is not clear .I need to know if someone swaps the UID of two applications in a device can they able to access the data stored of one application using the swapped id .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two applications that are signed with the same developer certificate can run with the same UID if you specify a common value for sharedUserId in the manifest file. Applications that are signed with different developer certificates cannot run with the same UID. If you root your device, you can modify the kernel and all bets are off, but this is not possible with a non-rooted/modified Android system.

If two applications are developed by the same entity, and signed by the same developer certificate, the common UID runs with a union of the declared permissions. So if app1 has permissions A and B and app2 has permission C, and they run under the same UID, they both will have permissions A, B, and C.

Comment: Sorry if my question is not clear .I need to know if someone swaps the UID of two applications in a device can they able to access the data stored of one application using the swapped id

Comment: I have not tried it, but they should be able to. All permission checks for Android applications are made based on the UID, so if that changes than the permissions should be affected as you indicate.

Comment: is there any possibility to change the UID of any application in device ?

Comment: is it possible to change uid of my app to uid=0 of root ?